# EC2 Instance Types with Fastest Download Speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm looking for the most appropriate EC2 Instance Type to download large files at a fast rate. There are several options of Network performances, and I'm leaning towards "Up to 10 Gigabit" or "10 Gigabit". Is there a recommended Model with this networking performance options that best fit the requirement? Would it be possible to download 4~6GB files in under an hour?

Answer (score 2):

Network bandwidth available to an Amazon EC2 instance is based upon the [**Instance Type**](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). Basically, larger instances have more bandwidth.

Instances that show 10+ Gigabit networking only provide this bandwidth **within the same Placement Group**, which is within one Availability Zone. It does not apply to Internet bandwidth.

You should **create a test** that you can run on various instance types to determine the throughput. Preferably **multi-thread** such tests so that you are fully-utilizing available bandwidth.

You should also experiment with running **multiple, smaller instances** because they might have more aggregate bandwidth than fewer, larger instances.

Comment: If 10 gigabit only works within the AZ, why was able to download a 3GB file in less than 20 mins, whereas in an instance with Moderate networking was taking over ~ 1.5  hours. Why is that the case?

Comment: From where were you downloading the content (from within the AWS cloud, or the Internet)? 3GB in 20 minutes would be about 21Mbit/s. I can get that speed on ADSL. A 10Gbit connection would be able to transfer 3GB in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors outside of AWS control which could potentially mean that you don't get the files in the amount of time you need it in. Some of these include:

- Server on the other side has poor upload speed
- Bad routing
- Internet backbone latency issues (can happen)
- Attempting to download from geographically far distances
- Existing network traffic to the instance
- The instance availability zone is down
- Amount of security group and NACL rules (increases processing time of individual packets)

Assuming none of these are issues you won't have trouble getting large files downloaded. For getting data to AWS at a decent speed from an on site location you can also look into [DirectConnect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) which helps on the routing front. For when you get into the petabyte+ level of data transfer there's also [Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/) and [Snowmobile](https://aws.amazon.com/snowmobile/) which is physical shipping of the data to AWS for loading into servers.

Comment: let's assume the best case scenario for the source - or other side and even the geographical strategy (they are in the east coast and so the instance will live on us-east-1). Is there a recommended EC2 type to use with 10 Gigabit Networking?

Comment: @extofer You could but the t2.micro instance type with "Low to Moderate" networking just downloaded a 1.45G ISO file at  10.6MB/s in 2m 24s. Given your requirements in the question 10 Gigabit Networking is a bit overkill. Also you might consider looking at enhanced networking as well (which if you just use official AMIs you'll get that)  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html#enabling_enhanced_networking to help improve things a bit.